# How do I send OTP from my server to my android application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, sms-gateway, one-time-password

I am using laravel 5.2 framework for my backend. I wanted to know about how to send OTP to an Android application from my backend. Can I use AWS-SNS or GCM or do I need to use some other SMS gateways. Also I want that OTP message to be sent from my custom ID such as VM-REDBUS. Please help me out guys.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. But, I wanted to know can I not do the same using any of the AWS services or Google services!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to integrate sms gateway to your backend. Which will send sms to your client mobile number.

You can see this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/) to understand the process of sms verfication.

You can choose sms gateway Solutions like [Kaleyra](http://www.kaleyra.com/), [Spring Edge](https://www.springedge.com/), [SMS Gupshup](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/), [Value First](http://www.vfirst.com/), [Msg91](https://msg91.com/) .

But for that you have to take mobile number from user as input then with backend you can send OTP messages.

You do not need to do any thing with android device about OTP messages. It should be on backend side. Suppose if you also want to integrate IOS then it would be helpful.

For more information you can see the tutorial also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. But, I wanted to know can I not do the same using any of the AWS services or Google services!

Comment: @AvinashJaiswal Yes you can achieve this kind of functionality with AWS services or Google services. we are working with AWS services also for our backend.

Comment: If not which one of the gateways that you have mentioned is the best for phone verification.

Comment: How can I achieve it using AWS? It took a lot of time as I wasted yesterday's whole day behind figuring out SNS. But I guess the documentation for the AWS SNS is a bit tricky as its difficult to understand.

Comment: @AvinashJaiswal you can use any sms gateway. you can ask them also for support to configure with AWS also or you can ask for AWS also for support. If this solved your doubts please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general step for any technology

1. register to kaleyra

   2. create apikey and notedown,
      apikey(ex: Abxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3) and
      SID(ex: sender id : HXAP0000000000IN) and
      api_name(ex: your_fav_name)
   3. build the url by any means 
      `https://api.ap.kaleyra.io/v1/HXAP0000000000IN/messages/api_key=Abxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3&type=OTP&body=Hello!%20Your%20OTP%20is%201234&to=+918055555555&sender=your_api_name`

      *or just edit url above*
   4. type should be `OTP`
      type, body, to ,sender is `mandatory fields`
   5. Now if you just paste that url on any browser You will get **JSON result**

```
{
       "id": "4xxxxxxd-2xx3-4xxe-9xx5-23dxxxxxxx2",
       "sender": "your_fav_name or SID alloted",
       "type": "OTP",
       "body": "Hello! Your OTP is 1234",
       "createdDateTime": "2020-01-16 04:41:10+00:00",
       "totalCount": 1,
       "data": [
         {
           "message_id": "4xxxxxxd-2xx3-4xxe-9xx5-23dxxxxxxx2:1",
           "recipient": "918055555555"
         }
       ],
       "dlrurl": null,
       "error": {}
     }
```

Here is the documentation link: https://apidocs-hexaap.kaleyra.com/?version=latest#df0f287d-0fb7-4e3b-82ee-bac581ecb0ae

*This is same for all kind of gateway technologies like twilo, 2factor, etc etc etc*

Answer (score 0):

here is the full SDK available for  [msg91 SDK](https://github.com/MSG91/sendotp-android)